# Why does the fifth port on this switch (Netgear GS305) look different?

Tags: switch

There's a gap between port 4 and 5, and there's also an extra space in the bottom of the inside of port 5. But nothing in the documentation seems to indicate that there's anything different about port 5. So I'm left wondering, why does port 5 look so different/special?

[image: Netgear GS305]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Industry, off-the shelf port modules usually come in sets of four (or eight, two, ....) and apparently Netgear couldn't source a set of five.

Switch ASICs often handle five (or nine) ports, so that you can cascade multiple chips to get the common 8, 12, 16, 24, ... switch sizes.

One of the switch-chip ports usually supports a higher speed (for the cascade uplink) but that isn't necessarily visible in the end product, especially for unmanaged switches. When cascading three or more modules, a higher-speed center switch is used to prevent an internal bottleneck. Combining three 9-port modules with a 5-port center module results in the common "24 standard-speed ports plus 2 high-speed uplink ports" model.